# Azure DevOps Git Merging master into feature branches with conflicts

Tags: git, azure-devops

Here's the scenario:

- Master has some new commits. This includes some global renames.
- I have a feature branch with different commits that cannot merge into master yet, but should be up to date with master. This includes new files.

I want to do a PR from master to the feature branch, and have branch policies for the feature branch to have a successful build.

The problem is, the renames in master need to be made to the new files in the feature branch, so just doing a PR of master into feature fails the build. And the renames cannot be done in the feature branch without duplicating most of the changes already in master.

Is there a way to checkout the changes being merged and make changes that can go into the merge PR? I was able to checkout the changes locally but only in a detached head state.

I wanted to know if this is possible without disabling the branch policy and doing two PR's.

Comment: This is a limitation of JSON build definitions; they aren't source controlled along with your code, so it's impossible to cleanly make breaking changes without builds breaking as well. If you use YAML pipelines, you can update the build pipeline YAML in the branch so that the build continues to pass.